# Autofac EasyNetQ: unit of work

Tags: c#, autofac, unit-of-work, easynetq

Autofac and EasyNetQ are almost all the time easy to work with but today we have kind of challenge: i want to set up unit of work for subscribers

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var container = AutofacContainerFactory.Build();

            using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
            {
                var bus = scope.Resolve<IBus>();

                bus.Subscribe<SomeMessage>("some.queue", container.Resolve<ISomeMessageHandler>().Handle);

                Console.WriteLine("Listening for messages. Hit <return> to quit.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

        }
    }
```

This is fairly easy subscriber in console app but how to properly setup UoW: i would be nice if some interceptor was called before handler Handle method was called and UoW was called after execution. Another resolution I can think of is do everything inside Handle method: maybe using some kind of UnitOfWork decorator pattern. I waiting for your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a AutofacMessageDispatcher that can do all that:

```
public class AutofacMessageDispatcher : IAutoSubscriberMessageDispatcher
{
    readonly ILifetimeScope _component;
    readonly IMessageContextFactory _contextFactory;
    public const string PerMessageLifeTimeScopeTag = "AutofacMessageScope";
    public const string GlobalPipeTag = "global";

    public AutofacMessageDispatcher(ILifetimeScope component, IMessageContextFactory contextFactory)
    {
        _component = component;
        _contextFactory = contextFactory;
    }

    static IEnumerable<IErrorHandler> GetErrorHandlers<TConsumer>(TConsumer consumer, IComponentContext scope)
    {
        var errorHandlers = consumer.GetType()
            .GetTypeInfo().GetAttributes<ErrorHandlerAttribute>()
            .OrderBy(attribute => attribute.Order)
            .Select(attribute => attribute.Initialize((IErrorHandler) scope.Resolve(attribute.ErrorHandlerType)))
            .Union(scope.ResolveNamed<IEnumerable<IErrorHandler>>(GlobalPipeTag), a => a.GetType()); // perform the distinction in the union on GetType so we only get 1 handler of the same type

        if (consumer is IErrorHandler consumerAsErrorHandler)
            errorHandlers = errorHandlers.Concat(new[] { consumerAsErrorHandler });

        return errorHandlers;
    }

    static IEnumerable<IPipe> GetPipeLine<TConsumer>(TConsumer consumer, IComponentContext scope)
    {
        var pipeLine = consumer.GetType()
            .GetTypeInfo().GetAttributes<PipeAttribute>()
            .OrderBy(attribute => attribute.Order)
            .Select(attribute => attribute.Initialize((IPipe) scope.Resolve(attribute.PipeType)))
            .Union(scope.ResolveNamed<IEnumerable<IPipe>>(GlobalPipeTag), a => a.GetType()); // perform the distinction in the union on GetType so we only get 1 handler of the same type

        return pipeLine;
    }

    [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
    public void Dispatch<TMessage, TConsumer>(TMessage message)
        where TMessage : class
        where TConsumer : IConsume<TMessage>
    {
        using (var scope = _component.BeginLifetimeScope(PerMessageLifeTimeScopeTag, _contextFactory.RegisterMessageContext(typeof(TConsumer), message)))
        {
            var consumer = scope.Resolve<TConsumer>();
            var pipeLine = GetPipeLine(consumer, scope).ToArray();
            pipeLine.Each(p => p.OnBeforeConsume(consumer, message));

            Exception exception = null;
            try
            {
                consumer.Consume(message);
            }
            catch (Exception e) when (GetErrorHandlers(consumer, scope).Any(p => p.OnError(consumer, message, e)))
            {
                exception = e;
            }
            pipeLine.Reverse().Each(p => p.OnAfterConsume(consumer, message, exception));
        }
    }

    [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
    public async Task DispatchAsync<TMessage, TConsumer>(TMessage message)
        where TMessage : class
        where TConsumer : IConsumeAsync<TMessage>
    {
        using (var scope = _component.BeginLifetimeScope(PerMessageLifeTimeScopeTag, _contextFactory.RegisterMessageContext(typeof(TConsumer), message)))
        {
            var consumer = scope.Resolve<TConsumer>();
            var pipes = GetPipeLine(consumer, scope).ToArray();

            Exception exception = null;

            foreach (var hook in pipes)
                await hook.OnBeforeConsumeAsync(consumer, message);
            try
            {
                await consumer.Consume(message);
            }
            catch (Exception e) when (GetErrorHandlers(consumer, scope).Any(p => p.OnErrorAsync(consumer, message, e)))
            {
                exception = e;
            }
            foreach (var hook in pipes.Reverse())
                await hook.OnAfterConsumeAsync(consumer, message, exception);
        }
    }
}        

public interface IMessageContextFactory
{
    Action<ContainerBuilder> RegisterMessageContext<TMessage>(Type consumerType, TMessage message) where TMessage : class;
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class ErrorHandlerAttribute : Attribute  
{
    public ErrorHandlerAttribute(Type errorHandlerType, int order = 0)
    {
        ErrorHandlerType = errorHandlerType;
        Order = order;
    }

    public Type ErrorHandlerType { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }

    public virtual IErrorHandler Initialize(IErrorHandler handler)
    {
        return handler;
    }
}

public interface IErrorHandler
{
    bool OnError<TMessage, TConsumer>(TConsumer consumer, TMessage message, Exception exception)
        where TMessage : class
        where TConsumer : IConsume<TMessage>;

    bool OnErrorAsync<TMessage, TConsumer>(TConsumer consumer, TMessage message, Exception exception)
        where TMessage : class
        where TConsumer : IConsumeAsync<TMessage>;
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class PipeAttribute : Attribute  
{
    public PipeAttribute(Type pipeType, int order = 0)
    {
        PipeType = pipeType;
        Order = order;
    }

    public Type PipeType { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }

    public IPipe Initialize(IPipe pipe)
    {
        return pipe;
    }
}

public interface IPipe
{
    void OnBeforeConsume<TMessage, TConsumer>(TConsumer consumer, TMessage message)
        where TMessage : class
        where TConsumer : IConsume<TMessage>;

    void OnAfterConsume<TMessage, TConsumer>(TConsumer consumer, TMessage message, [CanBeNull] Exception exception)
        where TMessage : class
        where TConsumer : IConsume<TMessage>;

    Task OnBeforeConsumeAsync<TMessage, TConsumer>(TConsumer consumer, TMessage message)
        where TMessage : class
        where TConsumer : IConsumeAsync<TMessage>;

    Task OnAfterConsumeAsync<TMessage, TConsumer>(TConsumer consumer, TMessage message, [CanBeNull] Exception exception)
        where TMessage : class
        where TConsumer : IConsumeAsync<TMessage>;
}

public interface IMessageContext
{
        object Message { get; }
}
public class MessageContext : IMessageContext
{
    public MessageContext(object message)
    {
        Message = message;
    }

    public object Message { get; set; }
}

public class MessageContextFactory : IMessageContextFactory
{
    readonly ILogger _logger;

    public MessageContextFactory()
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Action<ContainerBuilder> RegisterMessageContext<TMessage>(Type consumerType, TMessage message) where TMessage : class
    {
        return builder =>
        {
            builder.RegisterInstance(new MessageContext(message)).As<IMessageContext>().AsSelf();
            var forContext = _logger.ForContext(message.GetType());
            builder.RegisterInstance(forContext).As<ILogger>().AsSelf();
        };
    }
}


public interface IMessageContextFactory
{
    Action<ContainerBuilder> RegisterMessageContext<TMessage>(Type consumerType, TMessage message) where TMessage : class;
}
```

This allows you to:

- Register custom 'pipes' and 'errorhandlers' using attributes on your consumers
- You can register pipes and error handlers globally on in your container if you register them with the 'global' name
- You can resolve 'IMessageContext' anywhere in your dependencies to get access to the message
- if you use serilog, it will create a logging context including your message (otherwise just get rid of the ILogger references)

Sorry I just added the code quickly I might have missed some dependencies.
Here's a repo where I keep my EasyNetQ extensions if you miss anything:
https://github.com/zidad/net-tools/tree/master/src/Net.EasyNetQ

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yours code looks nice but i think for my simple needs it is overcomplicated or should I say too generic :) Check mine.

Comment: it IS generic, I didn't just write it for this answer :) But I have used it for a UoW pattern, and a simple saga implementation, but you can strip whatever you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class UnitOfWorkDecorator<TRequest, THandler> : IHandler<TRequest>
        where TRequest : class
        where THandler : IHandler<TRequest>
    {
        protected readonly Func<ILifetimeScope> ParentScope;

        public UnitOfWorkDecorator(Func<ILifetimeScope> parentScope)
        {
            ParentScope = parentScope;
        }

        public void Handle(TRequest request)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("UoW handler start");

            using (var scope = ParentScope().BeginLifetimeScope())
            {
                var scopedHandler = scope.Resolve<THandler>();
                scopedHandler.Handle(request);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("UoW handler end");
        }
    }
```

Test

```
   [Test]
    public void UnitOfWork()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<MessageCommandHandler>().As<IHandler<Message>>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<MessageCommandHandler2>().As<IHandler<Message>>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(UnitOfWorkDecorator<,>)).AsSelf().SingleInstance();

        var container = builder.Build();

        var handler = container.Resolve<IHandler<Message>>();

        var uow = container.Resolve<UnitOfWorkDecorator<Message, IHandler<Message>>>();
        uow.Handle(new Message());

    }
```

so the main idea is to create nested scope for resolving decorated handler.
Logic for managing unit of work can be resolved inside scope so for example decorated handler and uow can have same instance of EF db context.